# Sorting values in plt.bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have been looking around the net for hours now, and have not been able to solve this problem, and hope some of you can help.

```
plt.bar(att_new['player'], att_new['shots'].groupby(att_new['player']).transform('sum'))
plt.axhline(y=att_shots_leauge_average, color='r')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,30))
```

[image]

my dataframe looks like this:

```
att_new = att[['id','player','date','team_name','fixture_name','position_new', 'goals','shots', 
                       'shots_on_target', 'xg', 'attacking_pen_area_touches', 
                       'aerials_won', 'final_third_entry_passes', 'dribbles_completed']]
```

I have been going over: https://datavizpyr.com/sort-bars-in-barplot-using-seaborn-in-python/, but for me, it seems like the groupby I am doing, is making quite some problems but I need it to get the sum value.

Hope you can help! Thanks!

------**EDITED CODE**------

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# groupby and sort
dfg = att_new.groupby('player', as_index=False).shots.sum().sort_values('shots', ascending=False)

# get the mean value for everything
mean = att_shots_leauge_average

# plot
ax = dfg.plot.bar('player', 'shots', figsize=(9, 7), legend=False)
ax.axhline(y=mean, color='gray', lw=3)
ax.text(1.5, mean + 0.2, f'mean{mean:0.2f}', weight='bold')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You must sort the values with [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
- `plt.bar(att_new['player'], att_new['shots'].groupby(att_new['player']).transform('sum'))` is convoluted, do the `.groupby` separately, and then plot the result, as shown below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns  # only used for importing the data

# sample data
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# groupby and sort
dfg = tips.groupby('day', as_index=False).total_bill.sum().sort_values('total_bill', ascending=False)

# get the mean value for everything
mean_tips = tips.total_bill.mean()

# plot
ax = dfg.plot.bar('day', 'total_bill', figsize=(9, 7), legend=False)
ax.axhline(y=mean_tips, color='gray', lw=3)
ax.text(1.5, mean_tips + 0.2, f'Mean Tips: ${mean_tips:0.2f}', weight='bold')
```

[image]

Comment: ... I think it is getting late for me. There was.. 4. Thank you for your solution. It is just what I was looking for!